# How to use "as of" in this context?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to express that I read all the references citing a specific paper listed by Google scholar. I would like to add a specific date to that sentence. Is one of the following ways to do this correct? Or is there a more suitable preposition than "as of"?

```
I read all the 42 references citing A listed by Google Scholar (as of March 29, 2016).
```

or

```
I read all the 42 (as of March 29, 2016) references citing A listed by Google Scholar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As of" gives the thought that your information is current up until that date, and and your information would not include anything added after that date.

So in this case, I think using "as of" is proper.

I would put it at the end of the sentence, but I don't think that would affect the meaning any.

Answer (score 1):

> I read all the 42 references citing A listed by Google Scholar (as of March 29, 2016).

Here, *as of* could refer to either the date of your reading, or the date of the Google references. It is vague since your comment in parenthesis is outside the sentence.
My guess is that most people would say the date refers to the Google references, since it is closest to "Google Scholar".

> I read all the 42 (as of March 29, 2016) references citing A listed by Google Scholar.

Here, *as of* refers to the date of the Google references, since your comment in parenthesis is directly after *references*.

Using *as of* is fine, but you could leave out *the*: "I read all 42 references..."

Comment: So if the date is supposed to clearly state that 42 references were listed by Google Scholar on March 29. 2016, I would use the second variant?

Comment: Yes, because now there may be 55 references. You could put the "(as of March 29, 2016)" after "references", which I think flows better.